# how to get unknown amount of variables sent by url - C#

Tags: c#

In a webform i have the following tag:

```
<a href="download.aspx?file0=test0&file1=test1.......></a>
```

I don't know in advance how many variables are sent.

In C# i tried to get them all:

```
int cpt=0;
string[] pdfs = new string[];
while ( Request["'file'.cpt"] != null) //<-----ERROR
{
   pdfs[cpt] =  Request['"file".cpt'] ;
   cpt++; 
}
```

Unfortunately i have the following error :

> Too many characters in character literal

Can anyone help me to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Arnaud, this will only work if your link is in the following format
`<a href="download.aspx?'file'.cpt=test1&'file'.cpt=test2..."></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is specifically due to the line:

```
pdfs[cpt] = Request['"file".cpt'];
```

You should swap the single and double quotes so that it looks like:

```
pdfs[cpt] = Request["'file'.cpt"];
```

In C# a string must be quoted with double quotes.  Single quotes can only be used to delimit characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add the current value of the `cpt` variable to a `"file"` literal, but it doesn't work this way. Please try the following:

```
Request[String.Format("file{0}", cpt)]
```

By the way - this can be done quicker:

```
var pdfs = Request.QueryString
                  .Keys
                  .Cast<String>()
                  .Where(key => key.StartsWith("file"))
                  .Select(key => Request.QueryString[key])
                  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an unknown number of variables in the format you describe, you need to do this.

```
List<string> pdfs = new List<string>();
foreach(string k in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    if (k.StartsWith("file"))
       pdfs.Add(Request.QueryString[k]);
}
```